# How can I focus input in popup (Modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-frontend

I Have modal popup with this input. I want to focus when ever popup appears. 
I try to use onload focus function but not working for me. Kind help me in this case. 
Thank you
Here is html

```
<label for="postcodeSelectInput">{l s='Post/Zip Code' mod='prestadelivery'}</label>
    <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control" id="postcodeSelectInput" placeholder="" {if $selected_address}value="{$selected_address|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{/if}>
```

Here I have another js function using for floating label.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
  $('input, textarea, select').on('focus', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        label = 'label[for="' + id + '"]';

    $(this).addClass('has-value');
    $(label).addClass('has-value');

  }).on('blur', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        label = 'label[for="' + id + '"]',
        value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length <= 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('has-value');
      $(label).removeClass('has-value');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The main issue I am facing is. When we type the text in its label float up which works fine. When we save it and come back and open this popup to see the value we put before. Then label did not float up. it overlaps the value text,  And if we click (focus on input). Then label float up.  That's why I am thinking that input should focus when ever popup appears. so value and label not overlap.

Comment: Show us the code responsible for showing the popup.

Comment: @Lukasz This code is from prestashop. I am scare I can't find it. I can only get inside code.

Comment: @Lukasz The main issue I am facing is. When we type the text in its label float up which works fine. When we save it and come back and open this popup to see the value we put before. Then label did not float up. it overlaps the value text,  And if we click (focus on input). Then label float up.  That's why I am thinking that input should focus when ever popup appears. so value and label not overlap.

Comment: Try to add $('input, textarea, select').focus() right below the <script> opening tag

Comment: @Lukasz Thank you. It worked with focus. But it did not add class "has-value" unless I click on input again. Above function is already asking if input is focus than add class "has-value". But its not working with our autofocus function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion here in comments. There are two problems:

1. Focus on load. In your case you need to add:
2. Another is to have the events bound properly and triggered.

This could should do:

```
<script>

  $('input, textarea, select').on('focus', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        label = 'label[for="' + id + '"]';

    $(this).addClass('has-value');
    $(label).addClass('has-value');

  }).on('blur', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        label = 'label[for="' + id + '"]',
        value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length <= 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('has-value');
      $(label).removeClass('has-value');
    }
  });


  $('input, textarea, select').focus();

</script>
```